# Where is the open( char *filename, int access, int permission) defined?

Tags: c++, c, file

What file do I have to include in c/c++ to be able to use the open() function?
I have included fcntl.h, stdio.h and Visual Studio still tells me that "open" is not defined.

Comment: The Visual Studio standard library doesn't have an `open` function. It does have [`_open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx) though, and even that one is deprecated. I don't really recommended to use it (or its replacements) in Windows. Either use C++ streams, or C `fopen` and friends if you want portable file handling, or the Windows API functions if you don't care about portability.

Comment: And then some nitpicking. You really should take some time to  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You "have included"? Included *what*?

Comment: It depends on the language. There is no C/C++ language, so there are ovnly the two **different** languages C and C++. Pick the one you use!

Comment: if you [read the docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) you can see there are multiple overrides, it will be in either sys/types.h, sys/stat.h, fcntl.h. But an IDE with a parser/analyser should show you exactly which function will be used, from which header.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `open()` is quite standard - [it's POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html).  The "deprecation" is merely on the part of Microsoft.  There are many reasons a programmer might want to use lower-level `open()`/`[p]read()`/`[p]write()` instead of the higher level C++ streams.  Performance and portability come immediately to mind.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The deprecation is on the POSIX-y `_open`. _Deprecated_ means that Microsoft does not guarantee that this `_open` function will be supported in future compilers. E.g. with the Ubuntu subsystem, there's already a far better POSIX interface available.

Comment: @MSalters The "deprecation" is stated thus:  "These functions are deprecated because more-secure versions are available". "[M]ore-secure versions"?!?!?!  If *Microsoft's* version of `open()` is insecure, that's entirely *Microsoft's* fault.  Instead of giving up (and throwing FUD at POSIX in the process), fix the implementation - other operating systems have no security problem with `open()` - the interface isn't inherently insecure. What?  Linux, Solaris, HP-UX, OSX, AIX, Z/OS, Android, BSD can *all* implement `open()` securely, but Microsoft can't?

Answer (score -2):

as presented in the documentation :

[_open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx) is deprecated in favor of [_sopen_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w64k0ytk.aspx)

On the bottom of the pages in each of thoose link , you will see the required headers for both functions.

```
#include <io.h> // REQUIRED
#include <fcntl.h> // OPTIONAL
#include <sys\types.h> // OPTIONAL
#include <sys\stat.h> // OPTIONAL
#include <share.h> // OPTIONAL FOR _sopen_s
```

Comment: `open()` is a [standard POSIX function.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)  The "deprecation" is Microsoft-specific, and pretty much requires deliberately ignoring the POSIX standard.